# Upload files to Google Cloud Storage without downloading them locally?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I want to upload 120 files, each around 1.2GB so about 150GB in total, from an HTTPS website onto my Google Cloud Storage.

I really, really don't want to have to download them all locally, and then upload them individually.

Is there any way around this? Surely I can just give Google Cloud Storage a URL to pull from? I don't control the HTTPS server.

It seems to be possible to upload from S3 to Google Cloud Storage, but S3 seems to suffer from the same problem.

Comment: Why the close vote? Sure the answer is out there, but not in words such that I was able to find it by Googling... exactly the use case that SO was designed for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your website allows public access you can use the GCS Transfer Service to do it: https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/

Comment: Thanks! I did see that, but there is a requirement to include a hash of the object. Won't I need to download each file anyway to get the hash? https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/#urls

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to download them to get the hash. You could do this on Compute Engine (download the files and transfer them to GCS), otherwise I don't believe this is possible.